# How can jQuery fancy refresh an image div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few camera that uploading images trougth FTP connection.

I whould like to show the latest image with javascript, but I don't want to see white screens while the next image is loading.

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $('#image1');
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('https://alarmstudio.hu/<?php print($scriptfolder); ?>funkciok/kamerakep.php?ui=<?php print($_SESSION['userData']['user_id']); ?>&ci=<?php print($_REQUEST['kamera']); ?>&t='+ new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
            var $loader = $(document.createElement('img'));
            $loader.one('load', function() {
                $img.attr('src', $loader.attr('src'));
            });
            $loader.attr('src', data);
            if($loader.complete) {
                $loader.trigger('load');
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
<div id="load">
    <img id="image1" src="https://alarmstudio.hu/<?php print($scriptfolder); ?>funkciok/kamerakep.php?ui=<?php print($_SESSION['userData']['user_id']); ?>&ci=<?php print($_REQUEST['kamera']); ?>" alt="kamerakep"/></div>
```

My problem is: The image is not showing at refresh. The refreshing response appears as such:

```
ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC



%# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(ÿÛC



(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((ÿÀÐ"ÿÄ   
ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br    
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ 
ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B¡±Á    #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÝÿÚ? uÝG?ññÿ/øQý»¨ÿÏÏþ8¿á]ÂBæßÅPYÃ&Ëk½ÞrmvÔr¼éGÅmBæãÅsÙÍ.ëkM¾JmfèÐ·8ÉÉõ®e^cÙÇçÿ·u/ùøÿÇü(ö¥ÿ?<¸¿á^¥ý¿©ÿÂªþØûOüLç·¿óßgÝÆ>ï+/\ÿçÂ¸5S÷ú;¼¹¾î38Sò®ÝtªtcÓ×aû
```

I dont know what is this. It gives me code 200, but no new image. First time the image is showing...

Comment: What it is is probably the image bytes being rendered as characters. Open the image file in a text editor and you will see something similar.

Comment: May be incorrect headers? I see this in headers when the script get my php : `Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch
Accept-Language:hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your image is in binary format, which cannot be used as value in "src", what you should do is using it in base64.

Here an example: [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Plan B is to update just the link, but as you said probably the browser won't show an image during the fetching process.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer. This jquery script needs to get the URL of the next image not the image source.